# How do I get dataset object from chart object in chart.js typescript?

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I am trying to create new custom plugin for chart.js and having issues with type error while getting dataset option from chart object.

This is plugin code.

```
const gaugeNeedle: Plugin<"doughnut"> = {
  id: "gaugeNeedle",
  afterDatasetDraw(chart: Chart<"doughnut">, args, options) {
    if (!chart || typeof options.needleValue === "undefined") {
      return;
    }
    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea: { width },
    } = chart;
    const datasetMeta: ChartMeta<"doughnut"> = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
    const { rotation, circumference } = datasetMeta._dataset; // datasetMeta object hasn't got _dataset property
    ctx.save();
    const { needleValue, dataTotal } = options;
    const angle =
      (((1 / dataTotal) * needleValue * circumference - (90 - rotation)) /
        180) *
      Math.PI;
    const cx = width / 2;
    const cy = datasetMeta.data[0].y;

    ...
```

Here is chart options for doughnut.

```
  const data = useMemo<ChartData<"doughnut", number[], string>>(
    () => ({
      labels: ["Filled", "Unfilled"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Speedometer",
          data: [value, 100 - value], // Example data: 65% filled, 35% unfilled
          borderWidth: 0,
          borderRadius: 10,
          cutout: "85%", // Adjust for thicker/thinner gauge appearance
          circumference: 240,
          rotation: -120,
          backgroundColor: (context: ScriptableContext<"doughnut">) => {
            const chart = context.chart;
            const { chartArea } = chart;
            if (!chartArea) {
              return undefined;
            }
            if (context.dataIndex === 0) {
              return getGradient(chart, value);
            } else {
              return "grey";
            }
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
    [value],
  );
```

I want to get rotation and circumference from chart object inside `afterDatasetDraw`, how can I do that?

I have tried to log the `datasetMeta` to the browser console but it has `_dataset` property.
Above code is working correctly but I am getting only typescript error, and also I only want to get rotation and circumference for first dataset so if you know another way to get them, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with dataset metas, you can obtain the dataset also as `datasetMeta.controller.getDataset()` but this
will always have the type `ChartDataset`, [source](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/ac53fd282ee1a35512b532bb10bca9d74e2f8e41/src/types/index.d.ts#L608),
and not the `TType` specific `ChartDataset<TType>`, so you'll have to cast it to
`ChartDataset<'doughnut'>` (at least we're not casting to `any`):

```typescript
const datasetMeta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
const dataset = datasetMeta.controller.getDataset() as ChartDataset<'doughnut'>;
const { rotation, circumference } = dataset;
```

It's interesting that  `datasetMeta.dataset` property (without underscore) is always `null`.

Note that your approach will not return the values of `rotation` or `circumference` if they are not set in the dataset (e.g., you may set them globally in the chart `options` as `options.rotation`). In that sense, you can always use the `chart` object to retrieve those options directly, to the same effect as using dataset metas.